# How can i "reload" my string in a loop python

Tags: python, loops

So i have some code pulling a unique id from a webpage, i then use that id in a loop and when its used i want it to get a new unique id, i know i can put the code pulling ids into the loop, but i use the code to tell the loop how long it should run. So is there anyway i can reload the id without putting all the code in the loop?

```
followrequestsnumber = jsonfollowrequests.count("\",\"username\"")
approveid = jsonfollowrequests[startapproveid:stopapproveid]
while followrequestnumber >=1:
    uses the id on this line.
    loop ends and now i want to switch the approveid to a new one
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not something like this?

```
followrequestsnumber = jsonfollowrequests.count("\",\"username\"")
while followrequestnumber >=1:
    approveid = jsonfollowrequests[startapproveid:stopapproveid]
    followrequestsnumber = jsonfollowrequests.count("\",\"username\"")

    ...
```

Comment: I might have done something wrong but when i did that it was the same as before